MAUI Android - focus stuck on previous screens text field
Problem: Going from PasswordResetPage to PasswordResetSecurityQuestionPage , when I click in the text field on PasswordResetSecurityQuestionPage  and start typing, nothing shows in that field. When I go back to the previous screen(PasswordResetPage ), I see the new text I typed now shows there
Goal: Be able to type into the text field on PasswordResetSecurityQuestionPage
What I've tried:
Double checked: x:Name, Command Binding, tried manually setting/unsetting Focus/Unfocus in OnAppearing etc.
Code:
ForgotPasswordSecurityQuestionsPageViewModel.cs:
public class ForgotPasswordSecurityQuestionsPageViewModel :BaseViewModel
{
    private ForgotPasswordGetSecurityQuestionResponse _ForgotPasswordGetSecurityQuestionResponse;
    #region Constructor
    public ForgotPasswordSecurityQuestionsPageViewModel(INavigation nav, ForgotPasswordGetSecurityQuestionResponse fpgsResp)
    {
        try
        {
            Navigation = nav;
            _ForgotPasswordGetSecurityQuestionResponse = fpgsResp;
            SubmitCommand = new Command(SubmitAsync);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex);
        }
    }
    #endregion

    #region Command
    public Command SubmitCommand { get; }
    #endregion

    #region Properties
    private string _SecurityQuestionAnswer;
    public string SecurityQuestionAnswer
    {
        get { return _SecurityQuestionAnswer; }
        set
        {
            if (_SecurityQuestionAnswer != value)
            {
                _SecurityQuestionAnswer = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("SecurityQuestionAnswer");
            }
        }
    }
    #endregion

ForgotPasswordSecurityQuestionsPage.xaml:
        <Grid
            Grid.Row="2"
            Padding="10,0"
            BackgroundColor="{StaticResource Gray1}"
            HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
            VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
            <controls:CustomEntry
                x:Name="SecurityQuestionAnswer"
                Grid.Row="0"
                FontSize="14"
                HeightRequest="45"
                HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                Keyboard="Default"
                Text="{Binding SecurityQuestionAnswer}"
                VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" />
        </Grid>
        <!--  Submit Button Section  -->
        <Button
            x:Name="btnSubmitSecurityQuestionButton"
            Grid.Row="3"
            Margin="50,10"
            BackgroundColor="{StaticResource Green1}"
            Command="{Binding SubmitCommand}"
            FontSize="14"
            HeightRequest="55"
            HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
            Text="Submit"
            TextColor="{StaticResource White}"
            VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
            WidthRequest="180" />

ForgotPasswordSecurityQuestionsPage.xaml.cs:
public ForgotPasswordSecurityQuestionsPage(ForgotPasswordGetSecurityQuestionResponse fpgsResp)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.BindingContext = VM = new ForgotPasswordSecurityQuestionsPageViewModel(this.Navigation, fpgsResp);
}

